# How to combine form using React Js? [Snippet Attached]

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, forms, next.js

I am trying to make a form in reactjs like this https://jsonresume.org/schema/ (JSON Format).

**index.js:**

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import BasicDetails from '../components/basic_details';
import EmploymentDetails from '../components/employment_details';

const App = () => {
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('get the whole form json here');
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Dynamic Form Fields in React</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        Basic Details:
        <br />
        <hr />
        <BasicDetails />
        <br />
        <br />
        Employment Details:
        <br />
        <hr />
        <EmploymentDetails />
        <div className="submit-button">
          <button
            className="btn btn-primary mr-2"
            type="submit"
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          >
            Save
          </button>
        </div>
        {/* <pre>{JSON.stringify(inputFields, null, 2)}</pre> */}
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Compenents such as `<BasicDetails />` and `<EmploymentDetails />` code can be found in attached codesandbox.

Here I have made the form to have a separate components for each like,

```
---> Basic Details
---> Employment Details
---> ...So on ...
```

**Requirement:**

I am in the need to combine these inputs in a single json format [**like this**](https://jsonresume.org/schema/)

For now I have basic details and employment details which is in different files So how can I combine these two files/components to form a complete JSON?

Expected JSON format on click of the submit button (index.js):

```
{
  "basicDetails": {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
  },
  "companyDetails": [{
     "companyName": "xyz",
     "designation": "lmn"
   },
   {
     "companyName": "abc",
     "designation": "def"
   }
 ]
}
```

Look at the below codesandbox that has the JSON format of input fields in respective component.
I am in the need to combine those and display final form on click of submit button.

**Codesandbox:** **https://codesandbox.io/s/next-dynamic-testing-issue-forked-ieqf5**

*Note:* The component sections will keep on increasing like we will add new components like skills, education details (not added here but will add in future) etc.., so kindly provide the solution accordingly.

A big thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [`Context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) API. The idea is to have your state shared across multiple components.

The code below will hold a `formValue` that will be accessed on `EmploymentDetails` and `BasicDetails` components.

```js
// components/form_context.js

import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const FormContext = React.createContext();

export function FormProvider({ children }) {
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState({
    basicDetails: {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
    },
    companyDetails: [
      {
        companyName: '',
        designation: '',
      },
    ],
  });

  return (
    <FormContext.Provider value={[formValue, setFormValue]}>
      {children}
    </FormContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

On your `BasicDetails`, you access the `formValue` state above through

```js
// components/basic_details.js

import { FormContext } from './form_context';

const BasicDetails = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useContext(FormContext); // here
  const { basicDetails } = value;

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setValue((prev) => {
      const basicDetails = { ...prev.basicDetails, [name]: value };
      return { ...prev, basicDetails };
    });
  };

  ...
};
```

- also notice how we implement our `handleInputChange`, we're updating the `formValue` using `setValue` coming from our `FormContext`.

Check the demo, and ask me if you want to clarify anything. Read `Context` docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

[image: Edit next-dynamic-testing-issue (forked)]

Comment: This solution looks fine for me now.. I will accept it now and if I have any issues will get back to you.. Thanks..

Comment: Sure just let me know, np.

Comment: Sorry even though it is an additional feature, can you help me how exactly and efficielntly can we add validation to the inputs respectively?

Comment: Sure, what data you want to validate?

Comment: Thanks.. Name fields (first name, last name and in company details designation field) should not accept the numbers.. Then ```firstname``` in basic details and in company details, ```company name``` and ```designation``` input field needs to be required..

Comment: To be clear except last name all other fields needs to be required..

Comment: Firstname, last name and designation should accept only text and **not** numbers ..

Comment: It depends on how you want to show the message if the field is required, maybe on clicking submit check all properties if its a non-empty string, and show an `alert` message? For the "text and not numbers" I updated the codesandbox above.

Comment: Really thanks for your updation.. Every validation message needs to be displayed below its respective input boxes.. Even if the user is entering the number then the warning message can be displayed below the respective input boxes stating the name of the field.. Eg.., ```First name cannot contain names``` below first name input box..

Comment: Did you get chance to help me in displaying the validation message below input?

Comment: I think you should re-structure the `formValue` state that will also describe each value - like if it is required, has errors, possible allowed inputs. Sorry but I can't be more help regarding the validations.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. If you get time then please do help me in that..

Comment: Hi bro, Can you help me here in another question related with the above one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63614143/how-to-add-date-value-in-a-json-form-snippet-attached

Comment: I hope you can help me better in the above query as you are completly know the solution.. So please help me in the above query bro..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [possible solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/next-dynamic-testing-issue-forked-c0qm3?file=/pages/index.js). I only coded basicDetails but principle is the same for the remaining fields:

1. you have to handle changes from child components to parent component using *fieldChange* props:

```
    const BasicDetails = ({ fieldChange }) => {
    
    ...
    
      const handleInputChange = (event) => {

        if (event.target.name === 'firstName') {
          setInputField({ ...inputField, firstName: event.target.value });
        } else {
          setInputField({ ...inputField, lastName: event.target.value });
        }
        fieldChange(inputField);
      };
```

2. keep changes in your parent component state:

```
    <BasicDetails fieldChange={(value) => setBasicDetails(value)} />
```

Another solution would have been [useForm](https://react-hook-form.com/), depending on your project complexity

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. But my expected output is combining of basic details and company details and show it in a single json format on click of submit button..

Comment: Also your answer just prints the object as it is like ```{firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"}``` whereas my expected result is ```{
  "basicDetails": {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
  }```