# How to add date value in a JSON form? [Snippet attached]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, date, next.js

I am making a react app which has the form that consists of basic details and employment details section.

The form is almost done and also I am able to form a JSON structure for different sections.

**Complete working example here**: https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-css-only-carousel-forked-v7gg0

Now for employment details section, I am in the need to include start date and end date as an input field.

So I have made a custom month and year picker and included the same inside the components as **[monthpicker.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-css-only-carousel-forked-v7gg0?file=/components/monthpicker.js)** .

And from employment details section I have called the component using the code,

```
        <MonthPicker
          value={month}
          name="startDate"
          label="Start Date"
          onChange={setMonth}
        />
```

Using the following code, the selected value is updated,

```
  const [month, setMonth] = useState(
    `${`0${new Date().getMonth() + 1}`.slice(-2)}/${new Date().getFullYear()}`
  );
```

But I can understand this is the place where things needs to be changed but I am not sure of handling it.

[File where the monthpicker component included](https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-css-only-carousel-forked-v7gg0?file=/components/employment_details.js) .

**Requirement:** So if user selects the month and year from the picker, then that particular value needs to get updated in the JSON structure which doesn't happen now.

**Eg:**

If user selects the month as Jun and year as 2016 then the JSON format will be like,

```
{
  "basicDetails": {
    "firstName": "...",
    "lastName": "..."
  },
  "companyDetails": [
    {
      "companyName": "...",
      "designation": "...",
      "startDate": "06/2016"
    }
  ]
}
```

As it is possible to add additional rows, the selected value needs to get added to the respective inputs.

Really stuck for long and need some good help..

Comment: Do not format dates manually. Use `date-fns`, `moment`, whatever to format dates. Please.

Comment: @BertrandMarron, Could you please help me with that? I could not add additional libraries like moment js.. So could you help me with how exactly to achieve the expected result?

Comment: You have to make changes on your `monthpicker.js`, I don't see a need for it to accept a `value` prop.

Comment: @bertdida, Could you please help me out to modify ```monthpicker.js``` bro? Don't mistake me but I am beginner in react and your previous solution was helpful so If you help me in making the date value in ```companyDetails``` json object then that would be really helpful for me.. Hope you will provide right solution for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Undefined I'll be using the same code from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63595824/8062659) and will add the feature you're trying to implement on this post.

---

The reason why the changes of your `MonthPicker` component's value is not reflecting to the `formValue` is because you are passing the `setMonth` as `onChange` instead of `handleInputChange` — basically the changes are stored only on the `month` state.

Ideally we should be able to use the `MonthPicker` like below, where we accept an `event` from the `onChange` prop that we can use to extract the `target.name` and `target.value` properties.

```js
<MonthPicker
  label="Start Date"
  name="startDate"
  onChange={(event) => handleInputChange(index, event)}
/>
```

I fixed and refactored your [`MonthPicker`](https://codesandbox.io/s/next-dynamic-testing-issue-forked-8kz51?file=/components/monthpicker/index.js) component, so that everytime its `value` change like incrementing/decrementing the year and selecting a month we'll call the `onChange` prop passing its new `value`.

Please check the demo below and if you have questions just let me know.

[image: Edit next-dynamic-testing-issue (forked)]

Comment: Bro you are really helping me well.. I accept the solution as it works in codesandbox.. I will implement the same in my real app and If I have any doubts will ask you.. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

You are calling setMonth on change, but not passing a value:

```
onChange={(e) => setMonth(e.target.value)}
```

Comment: This results in ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined``` .. You can also feel free to try the same by forking the codesandbox that I have provided in question..